# How do I reduce code repetition by having to open a DictWriter in csv every time?

Tags: python, csv

I want to reduce the code repetition by having to create a variable with a *DictWriter* and all he information every time I need to write in a csv file.

```
class Example:

    def func1():
        with open('filepath', 'w') as file:
            csv_writer = DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')

            ...

    def func2():
        with open('filepath', 'a') as file:
            csv_writer = DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')

            ...
```

I thinked in create a private class atribute using the *open* function to pass the file, like `_csv_writer = DictWriter(open('filepath'))` to don't need to create a DictWriter everytime, but if i do that the file will not close like in the *with* manager right? So have any other option to reduce that code and still closing the file?

Comment: in `func2` it's not open for writing but for reading... Also, it's very unclear what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I just write wrong, but thx for the warning, i already edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily avoid the `open()` calls because they're in a context manager (unless you want to define your own context manager), but you can define a function that calls `DictWriter()` with your options so you don't have to repeat them.

```
def myDictWriter(file):
    return DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')

class Example:

    def func1():
        with open('filepath', 'w') as file:
            csv_writer = myDictWriter(file)

            ...

    def func2():
        with open('filepath', 'w') as file:
            csv_writer = myDictWriter(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between those functions is the `w` or `a` argument to `open()`.  So, pass that as an argument:

```
class Example:

    def func1(mode):
        with open('filepath', mode) as file:
            csv_writer = DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
```

Then you would call `func1('w')` or `func1('a')` as needed.

Comment: These functions write different things in the csv file and receive different parameters, i just simplified the code to focus in the important code snippet that I want to reduce, but thx anyway :)